# HIghlight row in red border in AdvancedDataGrid in Flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, flex4.5, advanceddatagrid

I want to highlight the row in red border in AdvancedDataGrid without selecting the row. My selected item is different from the highlight row. Please see the following image :

[image]

My selected index is where Territory is Nevada but my highlighted row is different(in Red Border) based on some condition.

So please tell me how can i implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to extend mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridGroupItemRenderer and add the condition + visuals to add the red border based on that condition.

Comment: Could you please provide me the code which can help me. Thanks you so much.

Comment: Look here for examples: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7bf2.html

Comment: Examples and answer not clearly defined..Please provide some block of code. It will help me.