# AdvancedDataGrid Row Highlight in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, flex4, flex4.5, advanceddatagrid

I am working in Adobe Flex 4.6 web application. I have a AdvancedDataGrid. I want to highlight multiple row in red border. If multiple row is highlighted in AdvancedDataGrid and i click or select any highlighted row or non highlighted row. Highlighted red border should not remove from these row and selected row(which i select or click) should not get highlighted. How can i implement this functionality.
See the below image :

[image]

Please help me. Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: How is this different from your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/38560401/4347580

Comment: Difference is If multiple row is highlighted in AdvancedDataGrid and i click or select any highlighted row or non highlighted row. Highlighted red border should not remove from these row and selected row(which i select or click) should not get highlighted. But in previous question its happening..

Comment: I want to highlighted multiple row based on the row index number. How can i do that. If multiple row is highlighted in AdvancedDataGrid and i click or select any highlighted row or non highlighted row. Highlighted red border should not remove from these row and selected row(which i select or click) should not get highlighted. Please provide some piece of code for that.

Comment: I am not using the Hierarchical data in AdvancedDataGrid so that is different from the mentioned URL.